# Recursion and Garbage Clean in Java

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I've inherited a code-base that does this:

```
private boolean method1(){
(several array lists created here)
...
...
method2(dataFromMethod1);

}

private boolean method2(dataFromMethod1){
     for (Item item : listOfItems{
        if (condition){
          (create some arrays)
           method1(passTheseArrays);
         } else if {
            (...same goes two more conditions)
       }
}
```

My question is the following: since we have `method2` calling `method1` from within the conditions (and then method1 re-calling method2 etc.) won't we have a memory leak since none of the methods return immediatelly and thus be garbage collected? I've been profiling the app via DDMS and get a lot of memory allocated for **buffer enlargement**.

With that thought in mind I proceeded de-coupling the methods (explicitly invoking the one and waiting for it to return, then invoking the other). Part of the problem seems to have been resolved, but the Garbage Cleaner is invoked **way** too many times.

Is there any advice as to what I could do in this context and what would be the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Each method will allocate data on the stack, as you are not directly returning, you might consume quite some stack space. As long as you stay within the boundaries of available stack space, there is no problem. If you have doubts regarding this, profiling is recommended. You've already been doing this and you're decoupling solution seems like a good fit to prevent consuming to much stack space, alternatively you could look at a specific design pattern (e.g. [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)).

Regarding the arrays that you are passing, an array is an object in Java. Objects are located on the heap. Objects references are passed by value, according http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx:

"*All objects are allocated on the heap area managed by the JVM. Every item that the developer uses is treated this way, including class objects, static variables, and even the code itself. As long as an object is being referenced, the JVM considers it alive. Once an object is no longer referenced and therefore is not reachable by the application code, the garbage collector removes it and reclaims the unused memory.*"

Thus indeed, as long as you keep a reference to your object it's not garbage collected. You can delete the reference as follows:

```
Object a = new Object();
// after this, (!! if there is no other reference to the object !!), 
// it will be deleted by the garbage collector
a = null;
```

Comment: One comment on your second paragraph: Doesn't java pass parameters by value? As for the nobody is using them anymore I do sense that if there is a reference to them they cannot be garbage cleaned. Correct me if I'm misguided.

Comment: Sorry for the misguidance, indeed everything is passed by value in Java, the correct statement should be "object references are passed by value". I've updated my answer.